# How can i click the third href link?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

```
<ul id='pairSublinksLevel1' class='arial_14 bold newBigTabs'>...<ul>
<ul id='pairSublinksLevel2' class='arial_12 newBigTabs'>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>
      <a href='/equities/...'> last data </a>  #<-- HERE
   </li>
   <li>...</li>
```

Question is how can i get click third li tag ??

In my code

```
xpath = "//ul[@id='pairSublinksLevel2']"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
actions = element.find_element_by_css_selector('a').click()
```

code works partially. but i want to click **third** li tag.
The code keeps clicking on the second tag.

Comment: Can you share more code? The real url would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("last data").click()
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("last data").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.newBigTabs#pairSublinksLevel2 a[href*='equities']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='arial_12 newBigTabs' and @id='pairSublinksLevel2']//a[contains(@href,'equities') and contains(.,'last data')]").click()
  ```

Reference: [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

Comment: it works perfectly, and i have question. Is it possible for equities in last two codes to be a partial path rather than a full path?

Comment: @Jeon As a contributor on StackOverflow I don't have a visibility of the actual [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). So while answering I prefer to construct the locators as canonical as possible so that the locators are proved to be unique within the actual HTML. I firmly believe that helps an OP to understand how _Css_ and _Xpath_ are constructed. Once you are through with the concept you can start constructing the _Css_ and _Xpath_ with lesser attributes. So **yes**, you can drop some of the attributes from the _ancestor_ and _descendant_ till the locators are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='pairSublinksLevel2']/li[3]/a").click()
```

EDIT:
Thanks @DebanjanB for suggestion:

When you get the element with xpath `//ul[@id='pairSublinksLevel2']` and search for `a` tag in its child elements, then it will return the first match(In your case, it could be inside second `li` tag). So you can use indexing as given above to get the specific numbered match. Please note that such indexing starts from 1 not 0.

Comment: if it is just to click on a hyperlink, you can use linkText instead of xpath. Please read it carefully OP wants to click on third li tag not on anchor link.

Comment: this code works. but i wonder why this code doesn't answer. is the code inefficient??

Comment: @Jeon Actually, this is an Answer but may have landed in the VLQ(very low quality) queue as the answer is a _code only_ answer without any textual context and may not be useful to the future readers.

Comment: @DebanjanB thx for answer, Then, is it better to use linkText?

Comment: While this answer is also correct (+1) I have constructed a canonical answer.